# what does grep -v '^#' do

Tags: shell

My program looks like this.

```
ALL=`cat $1 | grep -v '^#' | wc -l`
FINISHED="0"

for i in `cat $1 | grep -v '^#'`; do
        echo "PROBE $i"
 I will be doing some operation
FINISHED=`echo $FINISHED"+1"|bc`
```

I will run this script by giving a file name as parameter where a list of probes will be present.

I have 2 questions

1. What does `grep -v '^#'` mean. I learnt that `'^` is usually used to matching a particular string. But in the file name which I give there is no `#`. Moreover I am getting the total number of probes for `cat $1 | grep -v '^#' | wc -l`.
2. `echo $FINISHED"+1"|bc`. Here any idea as to why the developer as added `|bc`?

Comment: The grep bit only matches lines that don't start with #, if I remember my -v correctly. `^` is regex for start-of-the-string, and `#` should be just that. Unless I'm wrong, `-v` inverts matching, so you get any lines that aren't comments (as # is usually the conf file comment marker).

Comment: Also, if you're using the BASH shell, `FINISHED=\`echo $FINISHED"+1"|bc\`` can probably be replaced by `FINISHED=$((FINISHED+1))` -- eliminating the need to create an additional subprocess.

Answer (score 49):

- `^` means "start of line"
- `#` is the literal character `#`
- `-v` means "invert the match" in grep, in other words, return all *non matching* lines.

Put those together, and your expression is "select all lines that do not begin with `#`"

`|` is the pipe character, it takes the output of the command on the left hand side, and uses it as the input of the command on the right hand side. `bc` is like a command line calculator (to do basic math).

Comment: & to add, MANY (not all) languages have # as line comment character. So `grep -v ^#` would match non-comment lines.

Comment: Those languages usually allow comment to not start at the beginning of the line, so this won't work with lines like "<space>#<comment".

Answer (score 4):

I would use this to exclude comments from the code I'm reading. So all comment lines start with # and I don't want to see them if there are too many of them.

```
grep -v '^#'
```

Answer (score 0):

We have different ways for calculation. Pick the one which you like.

```
a=`echo 1+1 | bc`; echo $a
b=$((1+1)); echo $b
c=`expr 1 + 1`; echo $c
let d=1+1; echo $d
```